# OpenID reference problem in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to use OpenID in my website using asp.net_c#. I am working on asp.net forms website with asp.net v4. I am following the articles: http://danhounshell.com/blog/adding-openid-to-your-web-site-in-conjunction-with-asp-net-membership/ and http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/programmatic-openid-relying-party/

On the login button part I am getting referencing error saying the ClaimsRequest() type or namespace could not be found. I've already referenced:

```
using DotNetOpenAuth;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty;
```

I am using the latest DotNetOpenAuth.dll, how should it be referenced then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see `ClaimsRequest` Class is part of `DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.SimpleRegistration` namespace

http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.3/html/T_DotNetOpenAuth_OpenId_Extensions_SimpleRegistration_ClaimsRequest.htm